# C struct->struct->struct->element (usual) segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

Here is a weird thing:

I've got a struct, which contains pointer to a struct of the same type and pointer to the other type struct, as well as some other value.

```
struct animal {
    struct animal * father;
    struct race * rc;
    int age;
};

struct race {
    char colour;
};
```

Everything seems to be ok, when I access value age through father:

```
animal->father->age
```

But when I try to access colour of the father's race:

```
animal->father->rc->colour
```

I get "segmentation fault". But it would be too easy if it would hapen every time. It sometimes does, sometimes doesn't work and I don't know what is the factor that makes it unstable. The other thing that always work is:

```
animal->rc->colour
```

Is it possible that you can join up to two pointers and then the problem might occur?
I use up-to-date gcc.

Comment: You probably didn't properly allocate memory for `animal->father->rc`, but it's impossible to tell without seeing actual code.

Comment: Most likely you either forgot to allocate memory for a struct or you didn't initialise the pointer to the struct.

Comment: are you sure `animal->father->rc` is not null? whatever... the general suggestion is to analyze it with `valgrind` then run it with `gdb` and watch what's going on

Comment: There is a tool called valgrind (assuming that you are using unix like environment), it will help you to visualize where  the problem is.

Comment: Maybe you are missing to assign father sometimes

Comment: well, for tests I pointed father to the animal itself, so animal->father->rc->colour should be the same as animal->rc->colour, which always works. All the values are on their place when I try them directly.

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: Segmentation faults = pointer to unallocated memory. If you're getting seg faults sometimes but not others, it's a sign that you're corrupting the heap somewhere through use of unallocated memory, possibly somewhere completely different in the program. Have you tried running under valgrind ?

Comment: Try running it through `gdb` (simple primer here: http://cengiz.akinli.org/gdbprimer.htm), and print out the values of each level in succession. Like this: `p animal`, `p animal->father`, `p animal->father->rc` ... If you find a pointer that's 0, you've found your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine at times and doesn't at other times, the problem is almost certainly with memory allocation. If you could post how you've assigned the values right up from the declaration, you should be able to get help here soon.